# Scaling retina images in outlook (without using img attributes)

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, scaling

I'm developing templates for an automation tool, and have an issue scaling retina images in outlook.
I understand that normally you have to use the image attributes, for example: style="max-width: 100px; width: 100%;"

The problem is that if the users, who are going to work in template mode, will replace the images, the tool replaces the whole image tag (and thus my inline css).

I'm wondering if someone knows another solution for the scaling issue in outlook? Putting these styles on surrounding div's, tables, or td's don't work unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
        .deviceWidth {
           width:300px !important;
           height:auto;
          }
        }
     </style>
  </head>
<body>
    <table width="600" class="deviceWidth">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Retina Image (600) using media queries.
                <img class="deviceWidth" src="http://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2015/Flower_600.jpg" width="600" ><br/>       
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

According to [this](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/mobile-optimization-retina-images-in-email) article, it should be a valid alternative.

Hope this could help,

L.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid this is only going to replace the image when the screen is <479px. So what happens when a email is opened with outlook on a desktop computer?

Comment: That's true, the media query in the example will work only <= 479px.
But, what if you constrain your container to 600px and change the media query delimiter to 600px?
Another altrenative is to  declare a fallback outside the media query, so every condition non-satisfyed by it will have a safety net.

Comment: Makes sense! I'll go ahead and test this. Thanks!